# JSON / BigInt Json deserializer in play / scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to read some JSON String from request and convert them in case class in Play/Scala based REST application. 
My code is something like ...

```
 implicit val memberRead: Reads[MemberInfo] =  (
(JsPath \ "memberId").readNullable[BigInt] and
  (JsPath \ "firstName").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "lastName").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "janrainUUID").readNullable[String] and
  (JsPath \ "phones").read[Seq[MemberPhone]] and
  (JsPath \ "address").read[Seq[MemberAddress]]
)(MemberInfo.apply _)

implicit val addressRead: Reads[MemberAddress] =  (
(JsPath \ "addressId").readNullable[BigInt] and
  (JsPath \ "addressType").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "address").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "memberId").read[BigInt]
)(MemberAddress.apply _)

implicit val phoneRead: Reads[MemberPhone] =  (
(JsPath \ "phoneId").readNullable[BigInt] and
  (JsPath \ "phoneNumber").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "phoneType").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "primaryInd").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "memberId").read[BigInt]
)(MemberPhone.apply _)
```

But I am getting some compilation error(For all three readNullable[BigInt], memberid in memberRead, addressId in addressRead and phoneId in phoneRead ). Error is ...

```
 No Json deserializer found for type BigInt. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
```

My Case class are some like this ...

```
 case class MemberInfo(memberId : Option[BigInt],firstName : String, lastName : String,janrainUUID :Option[String] , phones : Seq[MemberPhone],address : Seq[MemberAddress])
 case class MemberAddress(addressId:Option[BigInt],addressType:String,address:String,memberId:BigInt)
 case class MemberPhone(phoneId : Option[BigInt], phoneNumber:String,phoneType:String,primaryInd:String,memberId:BigInt)
```

for janrainUUID :Option[String] I am not getting any compilation error , but for BigInt I am getting "No Json deserializer found for type BigInt"

Any one can explain why I am getting this error for BigInt and How can I resolve those? Actually those are PK value when I will do the DB operation for those, so they never may come with request. Is there any way to express that in play/scala like @ignore annotation in jersey.

Any help will be appreciated , thanks a lot...

Comment: Can I know the play version which you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/play-json/pull/122

Answer (score 3):

You need to define serializers for BigInt in the following way:

```
  implicit val BigIntWrite: Writes[BigInt] = new Writes[BigInt] {
    override def writes(bigInt: BigInt): JsValue = JsString(bigInt.toString())
  }

  implicit val BigIntRead: Reads[BigInt] = Reads {
    case JsString(value) => JsSuccess(scala.math.BigInt(value))
    case JsNumber(value) => JsSuccess(value.toBigInt())
    case unknown => JsError(s"Invalid BigInt")
  }
```

Just add this before memberRead serializer and you are good to go and also add error handling for invalid BigInt.

Comment: It is more complicated than that, what if the number is represented as json number and not string?

Comment: @FredericA. U were right. It was not able to represent json number. 
I have updated my answer so that json number can also be deserialized to bigint properly.

Comment: Alright, still kind of re-invents the wheel but at least it is not worse than what  can be build on top of what already exists in play.

Answer (score 2):

play-json doesn't provide a `Reads[BigInt]`. It only provides  a `Reads[BigDecimal]`.

You can either write your own `Reads[BigInt]`:

```
implicit val bigIntReads: Reads[BigInt] = implicitly[Reads[BigDecimal]].map(_.toBigInt())
```

or use play's `Reads[BigDecimal]` and transform the result:

```
implicit val memberRead: Reads[MemberInfo] =  (
(JsPath \ "memberId").readNullable[BigDecimal].map(_.toBigInt()) and
  ...
```

Edit: Both above solutions have the advantage of not re-inventing the wheel, they build on some well-tested infrastructure provided by play-json. As such they provide benefits that other solutions proposed for this question do not, mainly the correct handling of json string as well as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [Format](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#format) like this and use it in your companion object as implicit val:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import scala.util.Try

object BigIntFormat extends Format[BigInt] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[BigInt] = json match {
    case JsNumber(n) => Try(JsSuccess(n.toBigInt)).getOrElse {
      JsError(JsPath() -> JsonValidationError(s"error.expected.numeric(as BigInt), but got '$json'"))
    }
    case JsString(s) => Try(JsSuccess(BigInt(s))).getOrElse {
      JsError(JsPath() -> JsonValidationError(s"error.expected.string(as BigInt), but got '$json'"))
    }
    case _ => JsError(JsPath() -> JsonValidationError("error.expected.string"))
  }

  override def writes(o: BigInt): JsValue = JsString(o.toString)
}

case class SomethingWithBigInt(id: BigInt, str: String)

object SomethingWithBigInt {
  implicit val bigIntFormatter = BigIntFormat

  implicit lazy val format: Format[SomethingWithBigInt] = ({
    (JsPath \ "id").format[BigInt] and
      (JsPath \ "str").format[String]
  })(SomethingWithBigInt.apply, unlift(SomethingWithBigInt.unapply))
}
```

Comment: It is more complicated than that, what if the number is represented as json number and not string?

Comment: @FredericA., for that need to add just one more case.